# getting the original request out of the LOAD runner Custom request

Tags: loadrunner

we are having a custom request in been made in load runner. but we are not been able to take the original request out of it.

It is throwing a Bad Request for us.(400 code)
i am giving the body part of it
Body={\r\n"
        "  \"version\" : \"2.0\",\r\n"
        "  \"verb\" : \"UPDATE\",\r\n"
        "  \"date\" : {tstamp},\r\n"
        "  \"data\" : \"{\n"
        "  \\"upmId\\" : \\"{UpmID2}\\",\n"
        "  \\"nuid\\" : \\"5xxxxx-axxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx\\",\n"
        "  \\"dateOfChange\\" : \\"{NewParam}T{HHMMSSMSS}+0000\\",\n"
        "  \\"visibility\\" : \\"{Visibility}\\",\n"
        "  \\"locationVisibility\\" : \\"{Visibility}\\"\n"
        "}\"\r\n"
        "}",
        LAST);

what could be the original body part of the request mentioned above?
we have tried to remove the \r\n and replacing "\ with " 
 thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have two options I see:
1) Turn on extended loging. In runtime settings (F4) go to Log and select Extended Log, then check all three checkboxes. Run the script and you should be able to see what you need in the log of the step.
2) You can try to look at the raw snapshot of this step. Stand on the step with the cursor and open the snapshot view (Control+Alt+P). There you can see the various properties of the request.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the generation log.  This will show you the original (as recorded) submission and the web_custom_request() derived from the submission

Answer (score -1):

Did you mean where to find the whole request body on VuGen, if then you can switch to Snapshot tab(main menu-View-Snapshot) to view the request head and body of every step.